# When user inputs a number in a textbox will get an array element dynamically javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, input

i have an array:

var array = ['Mon','Tue','Wen','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun']; //JS

or i can get it like this:

$arr = array('Mon','Tue','Wen','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'); //PHP

i want to get "Mon" dynamically when a user inputs in a textbox num 1, 'Tue' when inputs num 2...
JS or PHP whatever.
please help.

Comment: `array[ this.value - 1 ]`, it's that easy

Comment: js: `array[i-1]`, php `$arr[ $i-1 ]`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the value of the array at that index in PHP you can use the form:

`$dayName = $arr[$number];`

And similarly in javascript

`var dayName = array[number];`

You need to remember arrays start at index 0, and the user input might start at 1.

Comment: <html>
<head>
  
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Input a number"> 
    </form>
        
        <?php
        
        $arr = array('Mon','Tue','Wen','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun');
        if(USER INPUTS 1){
        echo $arr[0];
        }else if(USER INPUTS 2){
        echo $arr[1];
else{
            echo 'Please input a number between 1 and 7';
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>

@mickadoo

Comment: Aw man, this is messy. I think the best thing you can do it look at basic php handling of forms (for example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)) and get that working first. Your form input is also missing a name.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just get the value of index then return the related value to user I would use javascript..

```
<html> 
    <head> </head> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() { 
       var array = ['Mon','Tue','Wen','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun']; //JS
       var first =parseInt( document.getElementById("textbox1").value);//store user input for control

       //Control user input.
       if(first<1 || first > 7 ||!Number.isInteger(first) )
       {
           alert("Please enter a number between 1 and 7");

       }

       var textbox2 = document.getElementById('textbox2');//get textbox2
       //control if index is defined and assign it to textbox2.value
       if(array[first-1]){
            textbox2.value= array[first-1];

       }
       //if not assign empty string
       else{
            textbox2.value= "";
       }
     } 
    </script>
    <body> 
    <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" onclick="myfunction()" value="get" />
    <br/>

    <input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" readonly="true"/>
    </body>
 </html>
```